# Wordpress - After I import Wordpress file while using All-In-One Migration, then I closed the browser? it shown error like this

Tags: wordpress, database-migration, web-hosting, custom-wordpress-pages, data-migration

After I import Wordpress file while using All-In-One Migration, then I closed the browser. it shown error like this. (I used Hostinger Hosting)

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'ComposerAutoloaderInit564f0d7c7a3ed0753d301c1d6e444524' not found in /home/u218179303/domains/manavissolutions.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/vendor/autoload.php:7 Stack trace: #0 /home/u218179303/domains/manavissolutions.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/app/AIOSEO.php(212): require() #1 /home/u218179303/domains/manavissolutions.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/app/AIOSEO.php(153): AIOSEO\Plugin\AIOSEO->includes() #2 /home/u218179303/domains/manavissolutions.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/app/AIOSEO.php(137): AIOSEO\Plugin\AIOSEO->init() #3 /home/u218179303/domains/manavissolutions.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/app/AIOSEO.php(368): AIOSEO\Plugin\AIOSEO::instance() #4 /home/u218179303/domains/manavissolutions.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/all_in_one_seo_pack.php(87): aioseo() #5 /home/u218179303/domains/manavissolutions.com/public_html/wp-settings. in /home/u218179303/domains/manavissolutions.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/vendor/autoload.php on line 7
There has been a critical error on this website.

Learn more about troubleshooting WordPress.
```

How do we fix this address?

Comment: Just deactivate your plugin for a while and visit the website again. You can do that by going to your `wp-content/plugin/` and changing this `all-in-one-seo-pack` to something else `all-in-one-seo-pack-backup`

Comment: If the issue goes away, try installing a fresh copy of the plugin.